# How to perform IS NOT NULL inside CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case

How can i get values that are not null from `C.Carrier` when the variable `@status = 'Completed'` , something like this

```
   WHERE CASE WHEN @Status = 'Completed' THEN C.Carrier IS NOT NULL END
```

Comment: why are you using is not null to put a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need `CASE`, just `AND`:

```
WHERE @Status = 'Completed' AND C.Carrier IS NOT NULL
```

If this isn't right, then it would probably help to see more of your query to understand the context.